# Python 2.5 and Tskill

Tags: python

I had the `tskill` operation working fine through a python script when using Python 2.7 but when I switched to 2.5 this code fails.

```
import os
import time
import win32com.client
os.startfile('cmd')
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
shell.AppActivate('Administrator:C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe')
time.sleep(2)
shell.SendKeys('tskill java + {ENTER}')
time.sleep(2)
shell.Sendkeys('tskill javaw + {ENTER}')
#shell.SendKeys('exit + {ENTER}')
```

I use `os.startfile` to run a python script that opens and runs the application(It's a graphics tool).

**Note: The application is already running by the time this script is called, hence I don't need to open it here.**

Can some one please tell me how to close an application successfully using this or similar method on Python 2.5. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have tskill on my system, but I think it's similar to `taskkill /F /FI  "IMAGENAME eq java*"`. Anyway, here's how to call a normal console application in the background (i.e. a hidden window) using the subprocess module (tested in Python 2.5.2, but using `taskkill` instead):

```
import subprocess

def tskill(*args):
    si = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
    si.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
    command = ('tskill',) + args
    rc = subprocess.call(command, startupinfo=si)
    return rc == 0

if tskill('java') and tskill('javaw'):
    #success
```

I used `call` because it only matters whether the call succeeds or fails, but in general you can use `subprocess.PIPE` to capture stdout and stderr using `subprocess.Popen`.

Edit: How to kill a process started with the subprocess module

```
command = ['path/to/executable', 'arg0', 'arg1', '...']
p = subprocess.Popen(command)
#do something

#kill if it's still alive
if p.poll() is None: 
    p.kill()
```

Comment: How do I run this as an  independent script though? Just save the method in a file and call it as `tskill('java')`?

Comment: I have a main python script that opens and runs the application,  it's called Processing. I need to now close that application and I want to do that using a separate python script. If I try to `tskill`through that script, it doesn't work whereas if i go directly to the cmd it does work. It's a thing with Python 2.5, I could do this with 2.7. So my question is how to use this code through a python script? Sorry if this got too long!

Comment: I start Processing with `os.startfile`